# Use SublimeREPL as Django shell

Tags: sublimetext, sublimerepl, django-shell

I am learning `Django`, and `Django` `shell` is a frequently used thing, but it is a bit frustrating to switch back and forth to the Terminal window.

I try to use `SublimeREPL-shell`, but it does not work properly. For instance, I can use `python manage.py shell` to enter the interactive console in the REPL window, but after that all command and results will not be displayed: it look something like this

```
bash: no job control in this shell
bash-3.2$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
```

Well, the results will be displayed if I `quit()` and they will all show up (but a bit too late...). Something like this

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> >>> [<Person: John>, <Person: Jane>]
>>> bash-3.2$
```

So I wonder if this is a way to do it properly?

Answer (score 4):

New a .py file in the path of manage.py. it contain these.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# run Django shell in SublimeREPL
# how to use: Meuns > Tools > SublimeREPL > Python > Python - RUN current file
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "[your app].settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(['.', 'shell'])
```

How to use: Menus > Tools > SublimeREPL > Python > Python - RUN current file